# Who was the first human to sleep - perchance to dream - on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, astronauts, spaceflight-firsts, sleep

Incidentally I don't mean "on the lunar surface, asleep laying on the surface of the moon" :)

So (A) who (if anyone) was the first human to actually be asleep (that is to say, presumably inside the lander) - *not* just a scheduled sleep time - on the Moon?

Bonus question: (B) is there a first (or any) known *dream* on the moon, presumably reported by one of the astronauts either at the time or perhaps later in a memoir or other recollection?

Related, (C) who (if anyone) was the first to actually be asleep when orbiting the Moon? (And which was first, C or A?)

Comment: "... that we know of"  :-) . Cue the alien abduction conspiracy theorists

Comment: @CarlWitthoft government conspiracy theorists also if the we means "common non-government folks". :P

Comment: We need a "stepoverflow" for these types of questions, don't We?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

1. > **(A) who (if anyone) was the first human to actually be asleep (that is to say, presumably inside the lander) - not just a scheduled sleep time - on the Moon?**

   It depends on your definition of sleep. Maybe [Buzz Aldrin](https://www.seattletimes.com/nation-world/apollo-11-astronauts-were-sleepless-in-the-sea-of-tranquility-on-moon), curled on the floor of the LM cabin:

   > The best Aldrin managed was a “couple hours of mentally fitful drowsing.” Armstrong simply stayed awake.

   If "fitful drowsing" doesn't count, then one of the Apollo 12 crew would be the first sleeper. [That mission provided hammocks for the LM crew, and they reported getting about 3 hours of sleep.](http://www.workingonthemoon.com/WOTM-Sleep.html) I would guess that (Lunar Module Pilot) Alan Bean fell asleep before (Commander) Pete Conrad, but can't prove it:

   > Conrad experienced significant shoulder pain due to improper suit fit and had to wake up Bean to let out the laces on Conrad's lower legs.

   From Apollo 15 on, the astronauts de-suited for LM sleep periods, and stayed for multiple days, so slept quite a bit better.
2. > **(B) a first (or any) known dream on the moon**

   That one's going to be harder to determine. I did some google searching with not much luck; in the mission transcripts, nearly every appearance of the word "dream" is in the context "like a dream" -- praising equipment or processes that are working smoothly.

   I did find this funny bit from Apollo 12, in lunar orbit prior to descent:

   > 092:07:53 Lind: Hey, listen. We've got one idea down here on the O2 consumption rate that we'd like to get your comments on. The suggestion was that, last night while you guys were asleep, the metabolic rates indicated that one of you was dreaming, probably about scuba diving, and that we think you were dreaming about petting a moray eel; and in the hyperventilation, you sucked up too much of the oxygen.

   While the scuba diving part is clearly a joke, I'm less sure of the "metabolic rates indicated dreaming" part.
3. > **(C) has anyone, and/or who was the first, to actually be asleep when orbiting the Moon?**

   According to [Working On The Moon](http://www.workingonthemoon.com/WOTM-Sleep.html), that would appear be Jim Lovell on Apollo 8, who reported sleeping briefly (~2 hours) during his first scheduled rest period after lunar orbit insertion. It's of course possible that he didn't really sleep at that time, in which case Frank Borman or Bill Anders could have been the first lunar orbit sleeper.

   [image]

Comment: This is a marvelous answer. <3

Comment: Would that I had points to give a bounty

Comment: got your bounty covered, @thanby

Comment: guys my pleasure to bountyize the hell out of this great answer!  cheers!